# Having trouble to get Binance's Websocket Market Streams

Tags: python, websocket

I am having a trouble getting some data from Binance Websocket.

The code is the following:

```
import websocket
import json
import pprint

SOCKET = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ethusdt@kline_1m"


def on_open(ws):
    print('opened connection')

def on_close(ws):
    print('closed connection')

def on_message(ws, message):
    print('received message')
    json_message = json.loads(message)
    pprint.pprint(json_message)


ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open, on_close=on_close, on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

In fact when I run the program there isn't any result printed on my screen.

I need help in spotting the mistake I have made in order for it to work properly.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code works for me. `print` should be unbuffered. Are you redirecting `stdout` to a file?

Comment: @craigb No I am not but it seems like the `ws` inside the three function is not recognised